# Use member.Id != turnContext.Activity.Recipient.Id in OnMembersAddedAsync?

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot

What does "// Greet anyone that was not the target (recipient) of this message." means?
The newly added user(s)? Or everyone in the conversation can see the welcome message?

```
protected override async Task OnMembersAddedAsync(IList<ChannelAccount> membersAdded, ITurnContext<IConversationUpdateActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (turnContext.Activity.ChannelId == "webchat" || turnContext.Activity.ChannelId == "directline")
            return;

        foreach (var member in membersAdded)
        {
            // Greet anyone that was not the target (recipient) of this message.
            // To learn more about Adaptive Cards, see https://aka.ms/msbot-adaptivecards for more details.
            if (member.Id != turnContext.Activity.Recipient.Id)
            {
                await SendWelcomeMessageAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
            }
        }
    }
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-activity-handler-concept?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#sample-activity-handler
[image]

Comment: @RajeeshMenoth Thank you. While it clearly prove the welcome message will be send to the new user only..

Comment: Your issue is resolved ? or still you have doubts ?